# handle sendasynchronousrequest with HTTPS in IOS?

Tags: ios, http-post, nsurlconnection

I have a HTTPS request.

i am using the `sendAsynchronousRequest` of `NSURLConnection`. i don't want to use

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

When i am using `sendAsynchronousRequest` of `NSURLConnection` then every time i am getting the following error

```
 NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
 CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
```

here is my code

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strService];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [strSoap length]];

[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];;

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[theRequest setValue:@"My User-Agent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[theRequest addValue:strSoapAction forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [strSoap dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:TRUE]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
    NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;


    strResponse=[self clearHtmlTags:strResponse];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictResponse=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:strResponse]];

    block(dictResponse);
}];
```

is this any other way to call the delegate methods of NSURLConnection with sendAsynchronousRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this delegate method. Hope it will work for you.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {

        // Verify certificate:
        SecTrustResultType trustResult;
        OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, &trustResult);
        BOOL trusted = (status == errSecSuccess) && ((trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed) || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified));

        if (trusted) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
                 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            if (1) {
                [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
                     forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            } else {
                [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            }
        }
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: but at where i should set delegate for this?

Comment: this is a delegate method it will not be called.

Comment: Why it will not called? You need to add protocol `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` in .h file.

Comment: it will called when i set delegate for NSURLConnection here for sendAsynchronousRequest i can't set for this.